# SELECT with INNER JOIN to count delta and filter results

Tags: mysql, inner-join, having-clause

I'm trying to select all rows from table B with same `id` and calculate delta for `count` value from table `A` and number of rows selected from B like this:

```
SELECT A.id, 
       A.count, 
       count(*) AS counter, 
       CAST(count(*) AS SIGNED) - CAST(A.count AS SIGNED) AS delta 
FROM table_A AS A 
INNER JOIN table_B AS B ON B.id = A.id 
GROUP BY A.id
```

Now i have `delta` calculated but can't filter results where `delta > 0`
I've tried to put `HAVING delta > 0` and `WHERE delta > 0` here and there, but no luck. Looks like i'm missing something with scopes in my query.

Comment: Database <> Table. In your case, you are "select all rows from **table**"

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT
    a.id, 
    a.count, 
    COUNT(*) AS counter
FROM cdb_A a
INNER JOIN db_B AS B
    ON b.id = a.id
GROUP BY
    a.id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > a.count;
```

Comment: Looks like in this case last `COUNT(*)` trying to count all rows in table_B on every row select and this query took infinite time to finish even if i have `LIMIT 1`

Comment: Performance is a something other than what your question above seems to be asking.

Comment: I mean that this count(*) will calculate total number of rows in table_b and not just rows where `b.id = a.id`

Comment: Actually, it won't do _either_ of those.  It will count the number of records to which each `id` record from the A table joined.

Comment: You right, works fine on my test DB here... Now i need to find the way how to optimize this request

Comment: @350D I am assuming that `id` is PK in your table `a`. For table b, define the index: `id` (if not existing, or no other index has it as the first column). Another thing, change `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(b.id)` and then compare the performance after index definition

Comment: I have indexes on every col in this query. if `A.count` added to `GROUP BY` list like this `GROUP BY A.id. A.count` even without `HAVING` filter - it wont work. Whout `A.count` works fine.

Comment: @350D Coincidentally, I was just going through questions asked in last few hours, and came across this (similar to performance requirement of yours): https://stackoverflow.com/q/58152039/2469308

Comment: @350D I think it is time for you to put a new question for performance improvement. For quick response, add `SHOW CREATE table` statement results for both the tables, as well as `EXPLAIN ..` statement result for Tim's query

Comment: Adding new combined index for id + count fixed this performance issue! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3):

Try using this query

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT A.id, 
   A.count, 
   count(1) AS counter, 
   CAST(count(1) AS SIGNED) - CAST(A.count AS SIGNED) AS delta 
FROM table_A AS A 
INNER JOIN table_B AS B ON B.id = A.id 
GROUP BY A.id) as t where delta > 0
```